# How to derive instances of Data.Messagepack 1.0.0

Tags: haskell, msgpack

The previous version of `Data.Messagepack`, [0.7.2.5](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/msgpack-0.7.2.5) supports [deriving instances via Template Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/msgpack-0.7.2.5/docs/Data-MessagePack-Derive.html). The current version (1.0.0), however, [doesn't](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/msgpack-1.0.0).

I was hence wondering if there is an alternative way to automatically derive MessagePack 1.0.0 instances, possibly using `XDeriveGeneric`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a stop-gap measure, have a look at the `msgpack-aeson` directory of the `message-pack` github repo:

https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-haskell/tree/master/msgpack-aeson

You could go from your data values <-> aeson <-> message-pack. Not necessarily efficient, but convenient since you can auto derive ToJSON and FromJSON with `DeriveGeneric`.

Example code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.MessagePack.Aeson
import qualified Data.MessagePack as MP
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

data Foo = Foo { _a :: Int, _b :: String }
  deriving (Generic)

instance ToJSON Foo
instance FromJSON Foo

toMsgPack :: Foo  -> Maybe MP.Object
toMsgPack =   decode . encode

test = toMsgPack (Foo 3 "asd")
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code how to do this exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own `GMessagePack` class and get instances by deriving `Generic`. I tried doing so to answer this question, but I can't recommend it.  msgpack has no support for sums, and the [one sum type supported by the Haskell msgpack library, `Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/msgpack-1.0.0/docs/src/Data-MessagePack-Object.html#instance%20MessagePack%20(Maybe%20a)), has a very poor encoding.

```
instance MessagePack a => MessagePack (Maybe a) where
  toObject = \case
    Just a  -> toObject a
    Nothing -> ObjectNil

  fromObject = \case
    ObjectNil -> Just Nothing
    obj -> fromObject obj
```

The encoding for `Maybe`s can't tell the difference between `Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe a)` and `Just Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe a)`, both will be encoded as `ObjectNil` and decoded as `Nothing`. If we were to impose on `MessagePack` instances the obvious law `fromObject . toObject == pure`, this instance for `MessagePack` would violate it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's for operation with a program written in another language that doesn't even support sum types, so their lack isn't a significant concern in this case.

Comment: The generic classes I didn't write for this will be the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/32107706/414413