# GHC Generics: How to write an implementation of (:+:) that converts sum types from/to integers?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I would like to write an implementation of

`instance (GMySerialize a, GMySerialize b) => GMySerialize (a :+: b)`

Where GMySerialize is defined as:

```
class GMySerialize f where
    gtoMyS :: f a -> MySerialize
    gfromMyS :: MySerialize -> Maybe (f a)
```

That will, for any sum type consisting solely of nullary data constructors (such as `data MyType = A | B | C | D | E | f`), convert it to and from `MySerializeInt`, where `MySerializeInt` is a constructor for `MySerialize` that takes one int parameter.

I started out with

```
instance (GMySerialize a, GMySerialize b) => GMySerialize (a :+: b) where
   gtoMyS (L1 x) = MySerializeInt (0 + rest)
     where rest = case gtoMyS x of
             MySerializeInt n -> n
             MySerializeNil -> 0
             err -> error $ show err
   gtoMyS (R1 x) = MySerializeInt (1 + rest)
     where rest = case gtoMyS x of
             MySerializeInt n -> n
             MySerializeNil -> 0
             err -> error $ show err
```

But realised that's horribly wrong, and am not sure how to fix it. How is it wrong? As an example, the following produce the same integer, but they should not as they represent different constructors:

```
M1 {unM1 = L1 (R1 (M1 {unM1 = U1}))}
M1 {unM1 = R1 (L1 (M1 {unM1 = U1}))}
```

I'm also unsure how I'd go about writing the `gfromMyS` instances even if I got `gtoMyS` working.

To phrase it another way, what I'm looking to do has an equivalent effect to writing a Template Haskell function that generates:

```
instance MySerialize t where
  toMyS x = MySerializeInt (toEnum x)
  fromMyS (MySerializeInt n) -> Just (fromEnum n)
  fromMyS _ -> Nothing
```

For every single `t` where `t` is sum types with only nullary constructors that implement `Enum`.

Comment: In what way is it wrong, and what is the definition of `GMySerialize`?

Comment: @JustinL. I edited it to explain why it's wrong and added the definition.

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure that you can tell, when you deserialize, whether you added 0 or 1 -- i.e. which case you took.  One way to do that is to make sure that `rest` is always even, so if the number is odd you know you added 1.  Just a little math...

Comment: Alternately, instead of adding `1`, add the size of the type on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to make another class that counts the number of constructors

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Functor ((<$>))
import Data.Tagged

import GHC.Generics

class GNumConstructors (f :: * -> *) where
    -- Is this close enough to CAF to get memoed in the dictionary?
    gnumConstructors :: Tagged f Int

instance GNumConstructors (M1 C c f) where
    gnumConstructors = Tagged 1

instance (GNumConstructors a, GNumConstructors b) => GNumConstructors (a :+: b) where
    gnumConstructors = Tagged $ unTagged (gnumConstructors :: Tagged a Int) +  unTagged (gnumConstructors :: Tagged b Int)
```

Then you can easily divide up the integers between those on the left side (less than the number of possibilities on the left) and those on the right side (any larger numbers).

```
type MyS = Int

class GMySerialize f where
    gtoMyS :: f a -> MyS
    gfromMyS :: MyS -> Maybe (f a)

instance (GNumConstructors a, GMySerialize a, GMySerialize b) => GMySerialize (a :+: b) where
    gtoMyS (L1 l) = gtoMyS l
    gtoMyS (R1 r) = unTagged (gnumConstructors :: Tagged a Int) + gtoMyS r

    gfromMyS x = if x < unTagged (gnumConstructors :: Tagged a Int)
                 then L1 <$> gfromMyS x
                 else R1 <$> gfromMyS (x - unTagged (gnumConstructors :: Tagged a Int))
```

Any individual constructor is represented by 0 and we peek straight through metadata.

```
instance GMySerialize U1 where
    gtoMyS U1 = 0
    gfromMyS 0 = Just U1
    gfromMyS _ = Nothing

instance GMySerialize f => GMySerialize (M1 i c f) where
    gtoMyS (M1 a) = gtoMyS a
    gfromMyS ms = M1 <$> gfromMyS ms
```

Combined with a `MySerialize` class we can flesh out a complete example for `MyType` and test it

```
class MySerialize a where
    toMyS :: a -> MyS
    fromMyS :: MyS -> Maybe a

    default toMyS :: (Generic a, GMySerialize (Rep a)) => a -> MyS
    toMyS a = gtoMyS $ from a

    default fromMyS :: (Generic a, GMySerialize (Rep a)) => MyS -> Maybe a
    fromMyS a = to <$> gfromMyS a

data MyType = A | B | C | D | E | F
    deriving (Generic, Show)

instance MySerialize MyType

main = do
    print . map toMyS $ [A, B, C, D, E, F]
    print . map (fromMyS :: MyS -> Maybe MyType) $ [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

`A` through `F` are mapped to the numbers `0` through `5`. Reading in those numbers reproduces `A` through `F`. Trying to read in a number outside that range produces `Nothing`.

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
[Nothing,Just A,Just B,Just C,Just D,Just E,Just F,Nothing]
```