# Haskell: No instance for own type

Tags: c#, haskell, instance, ffi

I'm trying to export own types to C# with using the "call-haskell-to-anything" package with this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module RectangleMover where

import Foreign.C
import FFI.Anything.TypeUncurry.Msgpack

data Point = Point Int Int
movePoint :: Point -> Int -> Int -> Point
movePoint (Point x y) dx dy = Point (x + dx) (y + dy)

data Rectangle = Rectangle { corner :: Point, width :: Int, height :: Int }
move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle
move r@(Rectangle {corner=c}) dx dy = r { corner = movePoint c dx dy }

foreign export ccall move_export :: CString -> IO CString
move_export :: CString -> IO CString
move_export = export move
```

When i try to compile this file i get the error message:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling RectangleMover   ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:19:15:
    No instance for (Data.MessagePack.Object.MessagePack Rectangle)
      arising from a use of ‘export’
    In the expression: export move
    In an equation for ‘move_export’: move_export = export move
```

So i think i have to write an "instance" for the "rectangle" type. But what is the correct syntax for this? I already tried to add :

```
instance Rectangle where
```

but got this error message:

```
test.hs:13:10:
    Expected a constraint, but ‘Rectangle’ has kind ‘*’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Rectangle’
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the library but it should be something like `instance Data.MessagePack.Object.MessagePack Rectangle where .....`.

Comment: i tried this, now i get: `test.hs:13:10:
    Not in scope:
      type constructor or class ‘Data.MessagePack.Object.MessagePack’`

Comment: You probably need to `import Data.MessagePack.Object` and use `instance MessagePack Rectangle where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved this with the help of ErikR ([How to derive instances of Data.Messagepack 1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892857/how-to-derive-instances-of-data-messagepack-1-0-0/31894075?noredirect=1#comment63770818_31894075)).
Here is the final code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module RectangleMover where

import Foreign.C
import FFI.Anything.TypeUncurry.Msgpack
import qualified Data.MessagePack as MP
import Data.MessagePack.Object
import Data.MessagePack.Aeson
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

instance ToJSON Point
instance FromJSON Point
data Point = Point Int Int deriving (Generic, Show)
movePoint :: Point -> Int -> Int -> Point
movePoint (Point x y) dx dy = Point (x + dx) (y + dy)

instance ToJSON Rectangle
instance FromJSON Rectangle
data Rectangle = Rectangle { corner :: Point, width :: Int, height :: Int } deriving (Generic, Show)
move :: Rectangle -> Int -> Int -> Rectangle
move r@(Rectangle {corner=c}) dx dy = r { corner = movePoint c dx dy }

toMsgPack :: Rectangle  -> Maybe MP.Object
toMsgPack =   decode . encode

p = Point 1 2
rect = Rectangle p 10 20
test = toMsgPack (rect)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you will need to import `Data.MessagePack.Object`. That will bring the class `MessagePack` into scope.

Then you need to say:

```
instance MessagePack Rectangle where
   toObject rect = 
      -- Insert your implementation here, returning an Object
   fromObject obj = 
      -- Insert your implementation here, returning a Maybe Rectangle
```

Compare this with the documentation for the [MessagePack class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/msgpack-1.0.0/docs/Data-MessagePack-Object.html).

Comment: Unfortunately i am very new to Haskell. What would be the implementation of toObject and fromObject in this case?

Comment: Take a look at the source code for the instances in Data.MessagePack.Object for some ideas. Its linked from the documentation page.